# AWS DynamoDB get multiple items by String an range with Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to understand a DynamoDB. I created a table and put some values there. But I completely don't understand how to get the item. And any docs which I found don't help.

I have a table with Primary partition key - channelID (String) and Primary sort key timestamp (Number). There are a few objects on my Primary partition key but each object by Primary partition key + Primary sort key is uniq. Everything I tried didn't work for me. I need just get 10 items with same channelID with order by timestamp desc.

My Java code:

```
String partitionKey = channelID;

            DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient);

            NewsEntityItem newsKey = new NewsEntityItem();
            newsKey.setChannelID(partitionKey);

            DynamoDBQueryExpression<NewsEntityItem> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<NewsEntityItem>()
                    .withHashKeyValues(newsKey);

            List<NewsEntityItem> theResult = mapper.query(NewsEntityItem.class, queryExpression);

            for (NewsEntityItem reply : theResult) {
                System.out.print(reply.toString());
            }
```

Comment: Can you show something you've tried? What does your query look like? Are you building a query via an SDK or directly in the DynamoDB console?

Comment: @mbaird I added the code.

Comment: code looks good. are you sure there are any items in that channelID?

Comment: Please show the code for NewsEntityItem. Perhaps you didn't use the DynamoDB mapper annotations properly

Comment: @ChenHarel Yes, the code works. I just don't know how to put in there "ordering desc" and "top 5 items only".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the AWS DynamoDB docs on how to use the Mapper api, look at the FindRepliesPostedWithinTimePeriod or FindRepliesInLast15Days methods
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaQueryScanORMModelExample.html

Comment: Yes, I saw it. Sorry, but I didn't understand how to get just top 10 items, without any cases with range like there.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the results backwards you should use the [withScanIndexForward](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#withScanIndexForward(boolean))(false).

In order to get only part of the results it is tricky to use the [withLimit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBQueryExpression.html#withLimit(java.lang.Integer))(5) even though this is what you probably looked at.

As you'll see in the limit documentation - setting limit is not exactly what you want, so you should also look at [queryPage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#queryPage(java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression)).

To conclude, use either and count 5 elements in Java code before breaking.